# Data Driven Pages with a small section of grid

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, data-driven-pages

I'm trying to make map book with data driven pages. Never a problem when it just a grid specified for the complete extent. 
But now i am using a grid that covers more than the area i want to print.
i was wondering if it is possible to specify wich pages to print, or to use in the layout.

Comment: Couldn't you just create a new .shp or feature class, from a selection of the complete grid, of the pages you want to print and use that as your DDP index layer? It seems like a simple fix, but maybe I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: Have you tried selecting the grid features you want exported/printed, and then running your export or print using DDP?  In the  dialog box there is an option to only use the selected index features.  Alternately you could create a selection layer in your TOC from your grid, and then use that as your index layer.

Comment: The way to do this is to put a definition query on the DDP layer to only show the pages you want.  Then, refresh your DDP and run again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a definition query on your DDP layer to only show the pages you want.

[image]

Refresh your Data Driven Pages.

[image]

Run your DDP again.  This will only print the pages that you specify.